# Reordering Favorite Tags and Ignored Tags lists?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, tag-watching, ignored-tags, preferences

Is it possible for me to reorder my lists of “Favorite Tags” and “Ignored Tags”?

Comment: Can I ask why'd this be useful?

Comment: When you have a lot of tags, it's easier to find the one your looking for if they are sorted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I do is delete them and re-enter them in whatever order I want. Assuming you do actually mean reordering the *tags*.

Comment: That's the only way I came up with.

Comment: I have scores of these.  :(

Comment: Same here, and the X is so easy to hit accidentally when trying to view a tag's page, which I just did to my favorite tag. Now I either leave it at the bottom (more scrolling) or remove-and-add twenty or more tags. :((

Comment: Not sure it's a new feature but now adding tags to those lists supports list of tags separated with a space. This means you can store the list of tags as a text file then at any time "restore" this with simple copy and paste instead of adding the tags one by one. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It is. I'm not sure where exactly it was announced on meta, but it was announced. That said I'll update this answer later.

Comment: @Iterator how is it useful to have scores of "favorite" tags?

Answer (score 15):

Deleting and re-entering the tags is the only way I have found. Here is a way howto speed it up:

1. Go to : `Unanswered` > `my tags`

   - at this point, the `Search` window contains all your favorite tags. E.g.

   > [cloud] [java] [performance] [ant] [mercurial] [svn] [debugging] [logging] [optimization] [jvm]
2. Reorder the list of the tags in the way you like, remove the `[` and `]`. E.g.:

   > java jvm performance mercurial  ant svn logging optimization
3. Cleanup your `Favorite Tags` and insert the new tags. You can **insert all the tags at once** by adding them all into the `Add` window.

Answer (score 4):

1. The tag lists in the sidebar and on the Preferences page are ***text which can be selected and copied*** just like any paragraph of regular text. Copy the text of a tag list, and paste it to a text file or notebook app.
2. Now you can reorder the list and do other changes in the text format. Tip: Your edited list doesn't have to be just one line, you can split it into several lines if you like. (I recommend you to save the document as a backup, in case [a bug like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175536/things-that-will-erase-your-favorite-tags-list) would happen again.)
3. To apply the changes, first remove every tag of the list on the web page. Then copy and **paste the modified list into the same text input field you would write tag names in**, and click `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

(To extend the existing answers for people with many tags)

You can remove all the tags this way:

1. Start editing the favorite tags by clicking `edit`
2. Type `javascript:$(".delete-tag").click()` into your address bar and press `ENTER`.
3. The tags are gone

Remember to export/backup your tag list before, as described in the other answers.