# Easily reordering/rearranging Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to sort/reorder interesting/ignored tags in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar)

By no means do I want to sound like gimme gimme gimme.

I am a generalist and working on [the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist), slowly, and I also frequent tags like [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [Networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking), [VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vmware) and the like to flag appropriately to be closed, migrated etcetera.

My tag list is actually quite large; just over 50 favorite tags, and I frequent them regularly, but in a different manner/pattern/approach from which I entered them and they now present themselves to me statically.

[Reordering Favorite Tags and Ignored Tags lists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/reorder-favorite-ignored-tags) seems to be the only option to rearrange your favorite tags. Without sounding like an inconsiderate fool:

- Would this be something that would ever be implemented?
- Has it ever been considered?
- What reasons can people give as to why it should not be a feature? ... I can't think of any reason not to.

Comment: So in 2009 "favorite tags" were called "interesting"? That explains why I didn't find that post in my searches. Sorry for the dupe. Thanks @random But, man it's 2012. You'd think we'd be able to drag and drop.