# Without deleting tags: reorder favorite/ignored tags

Tags: support, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

This related [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/reorder-favorite-ignored-tags) asks if it is possible to reorder tags and the one answer is that it can be done be deleting them and re-adding them in the desired order.

My question is if there is currently away to reorder favorite/ignored tags without needing to delete them?

I've noticed that I can actually grab a tag and drag it, but when I do cursor just becomes a 'no circle' (i.e. circle with a slash).  That has me wondering if it is possible and I'm just not doing it right...

Comment: At the rate that these feature requests are going, why don't we have a dedicated page for managing favorite tags instead?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn A new page doesn't seem necessary as the prefs page (i.e. <domain>/users/preferences/<user id>) already is dominated by tags with favorite tags, ignored tags, e-mail notifications for tags and questions, link to tag subscriptions.

Comment: Good thinking — I'd completely forgotten about that page.