# Things that would erase your “Favorite Tags” list

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags

When I was doing normal editing of my set of “Ignored Tags”, the set of “Favorite Tags” was suddenly emptied.

I suggest that if any of your tag lists is more than you can easily remember, [make a backup by copying the text of the list, and paste it somewhere else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175539/how-can-i-backup-my-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-lists) before you edit any of the lists.

Two ways to reproduce the bug:

- One way, which is how it happened to me, is spending a few moments repeatedly adding and removing tags in the “Ignored Tags” list, occasionally leaving edit mode by clicking on another part of the page. Eventually the “Favorite Tags” list will suddenly be empty.
- A more efficient way: The following steps will erase the “Favorite Tags” list (almost?) every time:

  1. Open two tabs with the Favorite and Ignored tag lists, either the Preferences
     page or a page with the tag lists in the sidebar.
  2. Click one of the 'edit' links and remove one of the tags.
  3. Switch to the other tab, click one of the 'edit' links and remove one of the tags.
     Click somewhere else on the page to dismiss the edit mode.
  4. Again click an 'edit' link in the same tab and remove one of the tags.
  5. Reload the tab.

I have reproduced this on Super User and Meta Stack Overflow using the current updates of Firefox and Google Chrome (OS X), with virgin browser settings (no extensions).

There probably are people who have *very* long Favorite lists. Is it possible for staff to restore a lost list if requested?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good catch!

There's an even easier way with only one tab:

- Click one of the 'edit' links and remove one of the tags.
- Click somewhere else on the page to dismiss the edit mode.
- Again click an 'edit' link in the same tab and remove one of the tags.
- Reload the tab.

Temporary workaround: before reloading click "Add".

I am putting this notice up to help people while I fix the issue.

---

The issue is now fixed and will be pushed out in the next deployment.