# How can I backup my “Favorite Tags” and “Ignored Tags” lists?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, tag-watching, ignored-tags, preferences

My lists of “Favorite Tags” and “Ignored Tags” are long and carefully crafted. How can I back them up just in case [Stack Exchange would forget them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175536/favorite-tags-blanked-when-editing-ignored-tags)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag lists in the sidebar and on the Preferences page are text which can be selected and copied just like any paragraph of regular text. So:

1. You can copy a tag list as text, and paste it to a text document or notebook app on your computer or in the cloud for safekeeping.
2. To restore a tag list, copy and paste it to the same text field you would write tag names in, and click `Add`.

(This can also be used for [reordering and other modifications of lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/how-can-i-reorder-my-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-lists/175545#175545), by editing the list in the text document. Tip: The edited list doesn't have to be on just one line.)